# Trigger Unit Test, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: unit-test

This works as a class. It has the minimal data I need to insert a record and run my calculation class (not shown).

I do see the results in my Earning__c table

```
public static void testInsert() {
    Earning__c eGoodInsert = new Earning__c();
    eGoodInsert.Name = 'Test 9';
    eGoodInsert.Pay_to_Account__c = [select id from account][0].id;
    eGoodInsert.earning_Owner__c  = [select id from user][0].id;
    eGoodInsert.contract__c  = [select id from contract][0].id;
    eGoodInsert.earning_type__c = 'Primary Sponsor Bonus';
    eGoodInsert.Contract_Amount_Hide__c = 0;

    Database.SaveResult GoodResult = Database.insert(eGoodInsert, false);
    System.debug(GoodResult);    
    System.debug(GoodResult.isSuccess());
    System.debug('DONE!!!');
}
```

but when I put it in the `@isTest` I get error.

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

for my first query `[select id from account][0].id`.

```
        Earning__c eGoodInsert = new Earning__c();
        eGoodInsert.Name = 'Test 9';
        eGoodInsert.Pay_to_Account__c = [select id from account][0].id;
        eGoodInsert.earning_Owner__c  = [select id from user][0].id;
        eGoodInsert.contract__c  = [select id from contract][0].id;
        eGoodInsert.earning_type__c = 'Primary Sponsor Bonus';
        eGoodInsert.Contract_Amount_Hide__c = 0;
        
        Test.startTest();
        Database.SaveResult GoodResult = Database.insert(eGoodInsert, false);
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assert(GoodResult.isSuccess());
```

It  won't insert the record. Why?

Comment: I can even hard code the values and it won't insert from the unit test.  Totally frustrating.

Comment: If I hard code IDs in the unit test, won't they fail when they get to production?

Comment: Why are you considering hard coding IDs? I see no suggestions from anyone about doing that.

Answer (score 2):

The error states

> List index out of bounds: 0

Breaking down the line on which the error occurs:

`eGoodInsert.Pay_to_Account__c = [select id from account][0].id;`

- `[select id from account]`

  Unless you explicitly limit them or use a `COUNT` method*, SOQL queries in Apex return a List, which is very much like an array and its members/elements can be accessed using array notation**.
- `[0]`

  You are specifically and intentionally attempting to access the first element in the List using said array notation.

As @sfdcfox stated in his answer, within a test class/method you do not have access to (most) of your org's data. Account records are inaccessible records, so you must create test data for your tests.

Therefore, to answer your question of "Why?":

- When your class/method is NOT `@isTest`, you have Account records in your org, so your SOQL query is retrieving them and you are specifically accessing the first one in the List.
- But when your class/method IS `@isTest` annotated, there are no visible Account records for it to retrieve. So your SOQL query returns nothing, you have a `null` list, and when you specifically attempt to access the first element of a non-existent list, you go out of bounds.  (Might as well try to divide by zero!)

---

**See [Apex Devleopers Guide > SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm)*

***Some exclusions apply. See the [Apex Developers Guide > Lists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm) for more details.*

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert all your data; by default, [test data is isolated from production data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm). Your unit test should create an account first.

By the way, as a shortcut, Apex allows you to assign a query as a value if you get exactly one row, so you can write:

```
eGoodInsert.Pay_to_Account__c = [select id from account].id;
```

You'll want to read that link, above, for specifics; not all types of data (e.g. users) are isolated in this manner. This exception mostly applies to Setup objects (those found in the Setup menu).

Also, when doing queries like this, consider adding `limit 1` to the query to avoid governor limits, etc.

```
eGoodInsert.Pay_to_Account__c = [select id from account limit 1].id;
```